# should i use .sheet for a Login Screen?

Tags: swift, modal-dialog

Currently, based on a

```
@State var isModal
```

I present a LoginView as a .sheet to the user of my app

That works nice, except for the fact that the user just can swipe away the modal view.

Which raises the question:

Is this the correct approach?

- should I trap the swipe or do some other checks to make sure the
  modal view is not dismissed? or
- is this not meant to be the way to do
  a login screen?  or
- are there properties to a .sheet that deal with
  this?

thanks for your insights

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my suggestion, I'll consider two login scenarios:

**Mandatory login:**

Apps like Gmail & Facebook requires the user to be logged in in order to use the app. In this case since user login is mandatory, it is recommended to design the UI in such a way that the user is made to focus on the login process. Unwanted elements including any gesture recognizer can be avoided.

**Optional Login:**

Apps like Quora & YouTube doesn't require any strict account wise binding. In these cases since the login action isn't compulsory, we can provide an easily dismissable screen, which also indicates the user that it can be ignored.

Design your screen based on your requirements and what you want the user to do.

In case you are going with the sheet, remember to handle in-progress tasks such as a network call, when in case the user attempts to dismiss the screen. With a full screen layout, a standard approach would be to provide a non-interactive animation, while we make sure the network call's response is received.

In short,

- Yes, you might have to make a decision when to appropriately allow dismissal.
- There is no strict rule. It depends entirely on the requirements. I'd generally prefer a full screen layout.
- [Present full screen modal](https://samwize.com/2020/07/21/how-to-present-full-screen-modal-in-swiftui/)